# Youtube API - Allows Subscribe User but takes away next day

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

we have a product that will subscribe a user to another user(s) after they go through and give us full permission to do so. The user is then subscribed to these other user(s) ... you can see this in youtube after the API is performed (seems successful) ... but a day later the subscribers are removed and gone? This always worked well. Anyone experience similar issues or know the why here?

When using the API with full permission scope, we Subscribe the user to a channel and we get varying results :

the Google_Service_YouTube_Subscription_Object is returned with valid data

The channel Subscription https://www.youtube.com/subscribers?ar=2&o=U may or may not increase in value (counter at top)

The channel Subscriber list https://www.youtube.com/subscribers?ar=2&o=U is not showing the new user (subscriber)

The user shows in their Youtube view that they are subscribed to the Channel

the user Comment on the video is displayed depending on the user privacy settings

the user Like on the video is counted

the NEXT day: comments, subscriber counts are removed from the Channel, likes on the video seems to stay

```
$youtube_client = new \Google_Client();
$youtube_client->setClientId(xxxx);
$youtube_client->setClientSecret(xxxx);
$youtube_client->setScopes(xxxx);
$youtube_client->setRedirectUri(xxxx);
$youtube = new \Google_Service_YouTube($youtube_client);
$resourceIdyt = new \Google_Service_YouTube_ResourceId();
$resourceIdyt->setChannelId($channel);
$resourceIdyt->setKind('youtube#channel');
$subscriptionSnippetyt = new \Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionSnippet();
$subscriptionSnippetyt->setResourceId($resourceIdyt);
$subscriptionyt = new \Google_Service_YouTube_Subscription();
$subscriptionyt->setSnippet($subscriptionSnippetyt);
$subscriptionResponse = $youtube->subscriptions->insert('id,snippet', $subscriptionyt, array());
```

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thanks for looking :) I think the code is working fine. We are thinking SOMETHING at Youtube is later removing subscribers, subscriber counts, and comments from the channel. Is their an automated process at Google/Youtube which targets API-based subscribers?

Comment: Is using the API to subscribe to a channel considered "spam"?

Comment: I'm not sure but it should not do that,  try filing a bug report regarding that behavior

Comment: We're getting a very similar issue.  Did you ever figure this out?  We've submitted a bug to Google but they're not acknowledging it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123781249

Comment: we have really gotten to the bottom of it. It seemed to "let up" a bit. please post here if you get anything back